# How do I create an if statement requiring a specific range of numbers from input

Tags: python, if-statement, input, range

Inside of this code you can see that I am creating a system where by checking the users credit score the base price of the property will change. Obviously I can't implement the discount prices because I can't create an if statement for those with a credit of 670 through 850. Please give suggestions.

```
# Prompt section for customer
credit_check = '''The listing of this property is currently at $1,000,000.
In order to continue you must participate in a credit check that will evaluate your options of payment.'''
print(credit_check)
answer = input('Would you like to continue on to the credit check?(yes or no) ')

# Results of Prompt
if answer == "yes":
    credit = input('Please enter your credit score ranging 300 through 850: ')
elif answer == "no":
    print('''Unfortunately we can not serve you unless you provide a credit check
    ,thank you. 
    Chandlers Estate Co.''')

# This is the piece of code that I'm stuck on.
if int(credit) ==  :
    print("hi")
```

Comment: Sorry if I have misunderstood, but a statement that would check if `credit` is between 670 and 850 would be `670 <= int(credit) <= 850`

Comment: Wow, that was the issue. Thanks alot man!

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is?

Answer (score 3):

You can write it in a way like simple mathematics.

```
if 650 < credit < 850:
    print("do something")
```

To exclude that range just put a 'not' after if.

```
if not 650 < credit < 850:
    print("do something")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for a "credit" between 2 numbers use code below.
You can use **>** to see if it's higher than **x** and **<** to check if it's lower than **x**.
You can also use **>=** to check if that number is **x** or higher than **x**

```
 if credit >= 670 and credit <= 850:
      print("hi")
```

Comment: You need to change the second condition to `credit <= 850` because otherwise you get a `SyntaxError`